# Not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I know it a old question but I can't fix it
here is my infor sdk manager
[image]

[image]

enviroment setup
[image]

run licenses permission and result

[image]

here is my licenses folder
[image]

but when run my app it show error 
[image]

How I can't fix my error?
Thank ervery one

Answer (score 0):

open your `android sdk manager`.

[image]

in your case the sdk `23.0.1` is missing license agreement. If its already installed delete it and install it again. On install screen make sure to accept the licence agreement given in radio box.

[image]

Clean and build again. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set correctly.

For instance, if it's C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\ instead of C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ everything may seem to work correctly until you try a Gradle build.